# How do I render check boxes with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm looking at the simple-form-bootstrap page and I can't figure out how to render check boxes.

Let's say I have four check boxes corresponding to four boolean table columns like in the example: Blog, Editorial, Announce, Advertisement.

The code looks like so:

```
<%= f.input :content_type, :collection => content_type_options, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

I'm guessing `content_type_options` would be an array of the four aforementioned checkboxes, right?  Well what do I put for `:content_type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple_form will bind the selected options to the `params[:content_type]` variable.

Note: `content_type_options` can also be a hash containing pairs of option/value. e.g. {'Blog' => 'blog', 'Editorial' => 'editorial', ...}

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.  So what do I put in for :content_type?

Comment: whichever you want. e.g. `<%= f.input :selected_countries, :collection => all_countries_array, :as => :check_boxes %>` puts the selection in variable `params[:selected_countries]` (which you can use in the controller)

Comment: Must :content_type be a field in the database?  I tried this `<%= f.input :pets, collection: User::PETS, as: :check_boxes %>` and got this error `undefined method pets' for #<User:0x007f6fdc02e088>`. If so, what type should `pets` be in the database?

Comment: in that particular case pets is a string (to save an array string representation).

Comment: if you want to use one table for users and another for pets you will have to use `f.association` instead of `f.input`.

Comment: Ok, I'm converting this site from PHP to Ruby/Rails.  My PETS array (or is it hash?) contains [["Dogs", "dogs"], ["Cats", "cats"], ["Other", "other"]].  Then in my database I had three boolean fields named dogs, cats, and other.  When a user checked Dogs on the form for example the column dogs in the DB would be set to '1' and so on.  Are checkboxes stored differently in a Rails driven DB?

Comment: Well I played around with it and looks like one string field in the database for 3 values works fine.